# Can anyone tell me what components they are in this picture, so I can google it?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Can anyone tell me what component is used to create these titles in a pic?

I want to put multiple titles, which are in red box from the pic,  in a frame.
I don't know what components they are.

Hope someone tell me what components they are, so I can google it.

[image]

Comment: Some panel, some panel and some panel

Comment: I suspect it's the way a particular look and feel renders a titled border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's basically a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout` and a raised `BevelBorder`, then another `JPanel` assigned to the NORTH border, which has a gradient background color assigned, and inside that panel is a left-aligned `JLabel` for the title text.